# Entity Framework Model and MVC Models can't map

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database-first ASP.NET MVC application and an entity model generated from the database, but I need to add some things to the model that are not generated. Like this to display a date correctly:

```
 [DataType( DataType.Date )]
 [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true )]
```

So I thought of creating another model, in the `Models` folder, and copied the exact same things that the edmx had and added what I needed. But this generates a problem, I cannot convert objects from the `EntityModels.Movie` to `Models.Movie`, how can I achieve this?

I've tried automapper but doesn't really work and the documentation that I've read is for the old version (pre v5) which has some obsolete functions. 
Here's my entity model code:

```
namespace Movies.EntityModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime>  ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ID_Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to reach my goal?

Comment: *I've tried automapper but doesn't really work* - what, so you're saying automapper doesn't work? You can report bugs here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues

Comment: Why don't you just add the fields/properties you want in a partial class?  This is fairly common practice when using Entity Framework.  It's the REASON the generated model has a partial modifier already on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just manually write an mapper as an extension method, its really easy.

```cs
public class Model()
{
    public string Test1 {get;set;}
    public string Test2 {get;set;}
    public string Test3 {get;set;}
}

public class Entity(){
    public string Test1 {get;set;}
    public string Test2 {get;set;}
    public string Test3 {get;set;}
}
```

now you create an extension method, for example "ToModel", to convert the entity object to your model:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions{
    public static Model ToModel(this Entity entity){
        var model = new Model()
        model.Test1 = entity.Test1;
        model.Test2 = entity.Test2;
        model.Test3 = entity.Test3;

        return model;
    }
}
```

and them, wherever you have your entity object, just call the extension method:

```cs
public JsonResult test()
{
    var entity = new Entity()

    //{  Fill your entity properties from your dataset or something }

    var model = entity.ToModel();
}
```

Comment: And where should i put the extension method? Any class or inside the model?

Comment: any class. Ahh I forgot to add, the extension method should be a static one

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new Public property lets say ReleaseDateFormatted in the same Movie model (in Movies.EntityModels) with [NotMapped] attributes.

Comment: Please re-write this as an answer. At the moment it feels more like a comment. You could include the change the OP would need to add as a code snippet, and replace the "Have you tried?", with "Do this". Commit